Is it correct to use "as quickly as he never had....."?
So I was reading something someone had written and I came across:

He < does something> as quickly as he never had in < time period>

It just seemed a bit odd to me and I didn't encounter such an expression on the internet upon research so is it correct?

Reminds me of  Shaw's quip that Brits and Yankees are two peoples divided by a common tongue. Almost illogical, yet not wrong. Playing with words.

... He had never managed to do it in under fifteen minutes; this time, urgency drove him and he managed it in ten. He did it as quickly as [Jim usually did] / [he had hoped] / [he never had {done before}]. //// It's unidiomatic, but as Yosef says, understandable and quirky. Use with care.

It sounds like someone's heard "as quickly as he ever had..." and tried to change the meaning without thinking about the actual syntax (just changing ever->never). I thought I might have heard something similar in a song or something else quirky, but Google throws up no hits.

I think never is inherently nonsensical in the cited context, since as quickly as actually requires a "real" referent against which to make the comparison, but never explicitly stipulates that no such referent has ever existed. So the text might be "syntactically valid" in the same way as Green ideas sleep furiously, but semantically it's total nonsense, so it's obviously not remotely idiomatic. I searched for several "variations on the theme" in Google Books, but didn't find a single comparable published written instance of as X as + never.

@FumbleFingers Do all comparisons require real referent? Does as never +"He dressed as he never had/no one ever had. "?  This one,  because of maybe the single 'as' sounds less odd to me .

@Abella: Good point. But whereas He dressed as well as he ever had is fine (on no occasion in the past did he ever dress better), He dressed as well as he never had sounds nonsensical to me (what are we comparing against?). It's not a matter of grammar - it's just logic / semantics.

No. When you say 'as quickly as,' the thing that follows needs to be a quick thing.

It's a bit like saying "as fast as not lightning."

With {do something} as quickly as, both comparands must have a degree of quickness.  Hence, "never had [done something]" is ungrammatical as complement there since a non-existent action cannot have a degree of quickness.

He ate lunch as quickly as he ever had [eaten lunch].
He ate lunch as quickly as he never had [eaten lunch]. ungrammatical

But you could say:

He had only  three minutes before the train left the station. It was a four-hour trip and the train had no cafe car. Since he hadn't eaten in two days, be ran over to the golden arches counter, bought a burger, and scarfed it down. He had never eaten a burger as quickly as he ate that one.

The sentence could also say, elliptically: He had never eaten a burger as quickly.
never is negating the asserted comparison, not referencing an eating action that never happened.

He had never {eaten a burger as quickly as he ate that one}.
Never had he {eaten a burger as quickly as he ate that one}.


its grammatically incorrect.  The problem lies in the double negative.
"Never" is a negative word.
"Had" is used in the past perfect tense, which implies something that happened before another event.
When you combine "never" and "had" in this way, it creates a double negative, which is generally considered grammatically incorrect in English.
Here are a few ways to correct the phrase:
"As quickly as he had ever" - This emphasizes the speed of the action compared to his previous experiences.
"As quickly as he ever had" - This emphasizes the speed of the action compared to his previous experiences.
“Faster than he ever had" - This focuses on the speed of the action itself.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
